# Git status ignore changed line endings

Tags: git, phpstorm

I'm struggling with git and ignoring line endings. This has been asked a million times on SO, but I still can't figure it out for my use case. So almost ashamed to ask ... here it goes.

Background info: I use the PhpStorm IDE to do most of of the git operations. Underlying PhpStorm relies on git to do the actual operations.

The problem i'm facing is that in PhpStorm I have a helper script that inserts/updates PhpDoc comments in existing files. This script uses LF as line endings (not configurable) and my IDE uses CRLF by default because i'm on Windows. I know I could set my IDE to use LF and convert the whole project to LF. But this feels like a last resort solution.

So after the script has updated the PhpDoc and replaced the CRLF with LF these files are listed when running `git status` and I don't want this. Git should ignore files that (partially) have different line endings. The reason i want `git status` to ignore this is because PhpStorm seems to rely on this for detecting the changed files and check these files by default for a commit. It's very time consuming to manually go over these files one by one to see PhpStorm tell me that "These files are identical" (except for the line endings that is)

I have tried [this guide](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings), tried all sorts of variations with the `core.autocrlf` setting and I tried dozens of solutions on SO and I still didn't find the the solution.

Trying all these solutions did teach me a few things about git, so if understand git the `core.autocrlf=true` setting is irrelevant in this case because this converts CRLF to LF on commit, but my goal is to exclude them from `git status`.
I've been playing around with `git diff --ignore-cr-at-eol` and this no longer shows the diffs, but git status still does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry to tell you but what you want git to do flies against what git is about and how it works. Git considers *any* change at the byte level to be a change and you *cannot* override this. It wouldn't make sense to. `git diff` allows you to do this *only as a convenience* so that when reviewing diffs you can focus on the relevant changes (e.g. just as many diff tools have settings to ignore whitespace changes).

I use Webstorm and it supports [`.editorconfig`](https://editorconfig.org), which itself supports different configurations for different files. I don't have time to test whether JetBrain's `.editorconfig` support will respect the per-file settings, but that may be your best option.

#### other alternatives

- write a script that strips out the CRs from the script. You could configure a [git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to run it automatically on commit. Once you do, I believe a checkbox in JetBrains IDEs will appear [in the commit dialog](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001808439-Before-commit-run-git-hooks).
- file an issue with JetBrains, as I know many editors that have a "autodetect line endings for existing files" option.

Comment: Okay, i agree with your explanation on git. It does make more sense the way it works now.

Comment: Good call on the `.editorconfig` I totally forgot about that. PhpStorm is Webstorm with added steroids for PHP and databases, so yes, it supports the .editorconfig file and honors it above your personal preferences. This way I can ship the editor settings with the project itself. Line endings can also be configured in PhpStorm under *File | Settings | Editor | Code Style* I'll set this to LF and convert at all *.php files

Comment: @Fluxlicious Are you converting all the `*php` files because you want to? You do realize that `.editorconfig` supports targeting individual files, e.g. the exact name of your helper script? See the [the example](https://editorconfig.org).  (btw, if this answer is helping you, I'd appreciate you upvoting it ;)

Comment: Yeah i know, but it would annoy me to death that some files would be LF and others CRLF. I'd rather have the whole application in LF then.

Answer (score 1):

> I know I could set my IDE to use LF and convert the whole project to LF. But this feels like a last resort solution.

It really is the best solution. The reason is that, as you point out, every time you have to deal with it you need to re-check the documentation and read it carefully. There is `core.autocrlf` and `core.eol`, and then `.gitattributes` per-file. And I think even with all that flexibility, there may be use cases that are still not covered. In my opinion, dealing with line endings is not worth the time.

Therefore, I always recommend do a sweep to clean the repo into whatever endings you prefer, and be done with it. If you cannot do it at once because you share the repo with many people, implement a hook to check new commits are in the correct style or even perform the cleanup automatically. Then wait a while until all common parts are done, and finally perform the final sweep.